# Is there an alternative matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices, terminology

Matrix multiplication can be thought of as a matrix of the sum of the products of the matrix elements.  That is

$\mathbf{AB}=\mathbf{C}$

where

$c_{ij} = \sum_{n=1}^\max a_{in}b_{nj}$

Is there a form of matrix multiplication where the result is the product of the matrix elements?  That is

$c_{ij} = \prod_{n=1}^\max a_{in}b_{nj}$

If so, what is the terminology?  Is it still called matrix multiplication?  Is there a whole different term for it?  And has there been much mathematics developed from this variant of multiplication?

Comment: Your first formula differs from usual matrix multiplication.

Comment: Do you mean like the Kronecker product?

Comment: coffeemath - oops.  Thanks for the pickup.  I have corrected this

Comment: The usual matrix multiplication (which you seem to have transcribed incorrectly) arises when trying to understand matrices as representations of linear operators acting on a space.  There is a geometric intuition behind this (think about how a matrix acts on basis vectors).  The Kronecker product has applications in probability and, it seems, robotics.  The Hadamard product (term by term multiplication) has uses in image processing.  What application does this proposed multiplication of your have?

Comment: CyclotomicField - Thanks for the term, but I'm not sure it is the same.  Kronecker products explode the number of rows and columns.  My question relates to a product that produces the same number of rows and columns that a normal matrix multiplication does, only with the terms multiplied rather than added.

Comment: Thanks Xander.  I think I fixed it while you were writing. My application is actually simply stating the different types of multiplication (scalar, vector, matrix etc).  I'll definitely add the Kronecker product thanks to your guys, but as stated above, my quick look at Kronecker product isn't quite it (unless it is a special case??).  It is closer to the Hadamard product, but still not quite the same.

Comment: Keep in mind that the actual matrix multiplication didn't arise in a vacuum - it's what you get when you think about how to represent **composition**, given the interpretation of matrices as maps between vector spaces. Briefly: if $A$ and $B$ are the matrices representing linear maps $f$ and $g$ respectively, then $AB$ represents the map $g\circ f$ *(to preempt a reasonable worry note that the product parses if and only if the composition makes sense; also, all of this assumes a choice of bases for the spaces involved)*. So it's not just some random choice.

Comment: Note the proposed multiplication always gives something rank 1, a product of products can be rearranged. So we wont have identity or the like.

Comment: One thing is for sure. If you say "matrix multiplication", I assure you people are not going to think about this operation, so my advice is don't call it that.

You may say this is yet another of the infinitely many possible binary operations defined on the set $M_{m\times n}$ of $m\times n$ matrices.

Comment: Jackozee Hakkiuz - which leads to the question, why do textbooks call it matrix multiplication?  Given how matrix addition is done, why does the Hadamard product not have the name "matrix multiplication", and what is typically called "matrix multiplication" entitled something different (perhaps something like "composition mapping" -> Noah Schweber?)? Introductory textbooks don't even mention the Hadamard product.

Comment: Your comment question "why did matrix multiplication get that name instead of the Hadamard product?" is asked but not answered very satisfyingly in [Why is matrix multiplication called 'multiplication' if it is non-commutative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1834925/26369). There is also [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034613/apparent-arbitrariness-in-mathematics?r=SearchResults#comment2108814_1034613) on the question "apparent arbitrariness in mathematics" saying that the Hadamard product probably didn't overtake standard matrix multiplication because it's less useful

Comment: This binary operation on square matrices is definitely a [magma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)). As @Artimis Fowl points out, we have no identity. I don't think this binary operation is commutative or associative. Maybe this is a nice example of a magma with no additional structure?

Comment: @Brendan because the primary purpose of matrices is to encode linear maps between vector spaces. That's why you write it as a rectangle: so that you can act easily on a vector and obtain another vector. Since the composition of linear maps is linear, it has to have another representing matrix. You could define matrix multiplication to be "the matrix that represents the composition of the linear maps". If you are not going to act on a vector nor to "compose" your matrices, then there's not so much purpose in writing numbers in a table. You could have put them in single row without problem.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $c_{ij} = \displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^n} a_{ik}b_{kj}=\left(\displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^n} a_{ik}\right)\left(\displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^n} b_{kj}\right)$.

For convenience, define a function $\mu$ that takes a matrix and returns the vector of the products of its rows, so that $\left(\mu(\mathbf A)\right)_i=\displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^n} a_{ik}$ and, using $\top$ for [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose), $\left(\mu(\mathbf B^\top)\right)_j=\displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^n} b_{kj}$. Then we have $c_{ij}=\left(\mu(\mathbf A)\right)_i\left(\mu(\mathbf B^\top)\right)_j$.

This means that the matrix $\mathbf C$ is the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) $\mu(\mathbf A)\otimes \mu(\mathbf B^\top)$. If we write vectors like $\mu(\mathbf A)$ as [column vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_vectors), then we can write $\mathbf C$ using traditional [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication): $\mathbf C=\mu(\mathbf A)\mu(\mathbf B^\top)^\top$.

Because of the above calculation using the known operation of "outer product" and throwing away all information about $\mathbf A$ (resp. $\mathbf B$) except for the products of the rows (resp. columns), I doubt there is a name for this $\mathbf C$ sort of product. However, I would be curious if anyone has encountered a standard name/symbol for what I called "$\mu$" above.